# Writing a dictionary with multiple items and values into a cvs file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I Have a dictionary with multiple keys and values as follows:

```
 My_data = {'key1': [item1 value1, item2 value2],
            'key2': [item1 value1, item2 value2],
            'key3': [item1 value1, item2 value2]}
```

Now, I need to write them into a csv file as follows:

```
      Item1    Item2   Item3

Key1  value1   value2 value3
Key2  value1   value2 value3
Key3  value1   value2 value3
```

Does Anyone know how to do that? I tried this code but does not work:

```
with open("dict2csv.csv", 'wb') as csv_file:
    for key, value in My_data.items():      
        csv_file.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))
```

Comment: What is this: `[item1 value1, item2 value2]`? Thats not a valid list.

Comment: How is it that the tutorial and documentation on (1) File output and (2) CSV package did not get you to writing even a single line of code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Yeh,I  Looked but I couldnt solve it

Comment: Open a file; iterated over the dictionary's key/value pairs; write the values to the file; close the file. [format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) may be useful. A [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) might help.

Comment: I tried this:  but I got errors
       
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for key, value in DicPercentMode.items():
            writer.writerow([key, value])
            csv_file.write( str(key) + ',' + str(value) + '\n' )

Comment: add that to your post then delete the comment please.  Did you read through the links @Prune gave you? Additionally [mcve]

Comment: @RZAKHK - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 1):

If you format your My_data correctly to be dictionary with valid key value pair and the value being a valid tuple or list here is one of the way you can get desired output. (assuming the value will be a tuple of (item, value)).

If your item and value are two words then you can go for approach 2.

This is basic coding, you would have to add error handling and other cosmetics to make it perfect for your input validation.

```
import platform

## Approach 1
My_data = {'key1': [('item1','value1'),('item2','value2')], 'key2': [('item1','value1'), ('item2','value2')], 'key3': [('item1','value1'), ('item2','value2'), ('item3','value3')]}

print("Python version : " + platform.python_version())

print()

print("Approach 1 with formatted My_data")
with open("dict2csv1.csv", 'w') as output:
    ## print data
    for key, values in My_data.items():
        data = ""
        for value in values:
            data = data + value[1] + ","
        data = key + "," + data[:-1] + "\n"
        ## display on console for debugging
        print(data, end='')
        output.write(data)

print()

## Approach 2    
print("Approach 2 with given My_data")
My_data = {'key1': ['item1 value1', 'item2 value2'], 'key2': ['item1 value1', 'item2 value2'], 'key3': ['item1 value1', 'item2 value2', 'item3 value3']}
with open("dict2csv2.csv", 'w') as output:
    ## print data
    for key, values in My_data.items():
        data = ""
        for value in values:
            valueItems = value.split()
            data = data + valueItems[1] + ","
        data = key + "," + data[:-1] + "\n"
        ## display on console for debugging
        print(data, end='')
        output.write(data)
```

Sample Run (key3 has more than 2 items i.e. each key having different number of items)

```
Python version : 3.6.1

Approach 1 with formatted My_data
key1,value1,value2
key2,value1,value2
key3,value1,value2,value3

Approach 2 with given My_data
key1,value1,value2
key2,value1,value2
key3,value1,value2,value3
```